# Equation of the hyperplane that passes through points on the different axes

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, vector-spaces

We work over $\mathbb{R}^N$. I have a set of points, each of which is on a different axis. For instance, when $N=3$ the set is given by $S=\{ (p_1,0,0);(0,p_2,0);(0,0,p_3) \}$, where $p_1$, $p_2$, and $p_3$ are some positive real numbers. 
For the general case, I need to find the equation of the hyperplane that passes through these points.
In other words, since we know that the equation of a hyperplane is given by $\sum_i^N a_i x_i=b$, how we can find the $a_i$s and $b$ in function of the $p_i$s.

Comment: @mlainz The OP states that the $p_i$'s are positive real numbers.

Comment: In my case, the $p_i$'s are $\ne0$. What happens if $p_i$ can be zero ?

Comment: Take my answer, clear the fractions, and you'll get an answer for when $p_i$'s are zero.  Note that the solution might not be unique if more than one $p_i$ is zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\mathbb{R}^3$, you have
$$
\frac{1}{p_x}x+\frac{1}{p_y}y+\frac{1}{p_z}z=1.
$$
Generalize for higher dimensions.